# Configuring the apache2.conf to handle concurrent request

Tags: php, ubuntu, concurrency, apache2, apache2-module

I have Apache installed on Hyper-V Ubuntu system. Currently, 2GB RAM allotted to the vm machine. I have heavy PHP service uploaded to Apache which typically handle the 1000 max concurrent request at single instance of time. I need a help to setting up the Prefork configuration from apache2.conf file so that my php web service will able to handle max concurrent request.

Default apache2 Prefork setting is as follows.

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers 4
MaxClients 100
MinSpareThreads 10
MaxSpareThreads 50
ThreadsPerChild 20
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use mpm_worker module ,this will allow you to serve lot of concurrent request using less memory. but you need to increase your maxrequest per child, startservers , max clients etc.